# Can an infinitive verb be put after a relative pronoun?

Tags: grammaire

If you were to say "That's all to talk about" in French, could you say

> C'est tout dont parler

Or is this wrong? Can relative pronouns be followed by infinitive verbs?

Comment: Before the relative pronoun you need an antecedent (noun or pronoun, tout is neither) and the verb *parler* needs a subject... so it can't be the infinitive...  Use "ce  dont" as relative pronoun (*ce* plays the part of the antecedent, summing up what come before) and build a sentence around *parler* (e.g. .. on peut parler). But *ce qui* would probably be better here : "... tout ce qu'il y a à dire".

Answer (score 1):

As Laure said, it would be **C'est tout ce dont parler**. It's correct but it's a bit formal, we would better say **C'est tout ce dont on va/peut/veut/doit/*whatever* parler**.

Comment: More than formal, it's difficult to understand. It should really be avoided.